# Download file to Windows Phone with c# and OneDrive API

Tags: c#, download, local-storage, onedrive

Someone knows how to make downloading files to phone?
I made a request and received items:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(String.Format("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/special/approot/children?access_token={0}", token));
var text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I have them id, and now i must do nex request:

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{ID}/content
```

But how to make downloading a file in the local storage application? (file format is .txt)

Comment: Check out this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/761490/How-to-use-Onedrive-Features-in-a-Windows-Phone).

Answer (score 0):

Once you've made the request to download the content, you should receive a HTTP 302 response.  To download the file, you'll need to follow the URL provided in the Location header of the response.  You can then use the FileSavePicker class to save the file locally.  More info on the FileSavePicker can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.aspx .  I hope that helps.